# Heavy multicast traffic created by Jboss 5 AS cluster

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

We have a Jboss 5 AS cluster consiteing of 2 nodes using multicast, every thing works fine and the servers are able to discover and make a cluster

but the problem is these servers generate heavy multicast traffic which effects the network performace of other servers shareing the same network.

I am new to Jboss clustering is there any way to use unicast (point-to-point) instead of multicast ? Or configure the multicast such that its not problem for rest of the network ? can you refer me to some documentation , blog post or simmillar that can help me get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't got any answers here but this might be of help to someone in future we managed to resolve it by

Set the following TTL property for jboss in the start up script

```
-Djgroups.udp.ip_ttl=1
```

this will restrict the number of hops to 1 for the multicast messages. This will not reduce the amount of network traffic between the clustered JBoss but will prevent it spreading outside.

If you have other servers in the same subnet that are effected by flooding problem then 
you might have to switch to TCP stack and do unicast instead of multicast

```
-Djboss.default.jgroups.stack=tcp
```

Also there are more configuration files in jboss deploy for clustering that you should look at.

```
server/production/deploy/cluster/jboss-cache-manager.sar/META-INF/jboss-cache-manager-jboss-beans.xml
```

and other conf files in the  JGroups config.

Answer (score 0):

If multicast is not an option of for some reason it doesn't work due to network topology we can use the unicast.

To use unicast clustering instead of UDP mcast. Open up your profile and look into file jgroups-channelfactory-stacks.xml and locate the stack named "tcp". That stacks still uses UDP only for multicast discovery. If low UDP traffic is alright, you dont need to change it. If it is or mcast doesn't work, you will need to configure TCPPING protocol and configure intial_hosts where to look for cluster members.

Afterwards, you will need to tell JBoss Cache to use this stack, open up jboss-cache-manager-jboss-beans.xml where for each cache you have a stack defined. You can either change it here from udp to tcp or you can simply use the property when starting AS, just add:

`-Djboss.default.jgroups.stack=tcp`